# Can I write my own view in asp mvc 3 razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Usually I have a simillar code with this

```
puclic class FooController{

    public ActionResult Index(){
         return View(DbContext.Foo.ToList());
    }

     public ActionResult Create(){
         return View(new FooModel());
    }
}
```

I want to replace return View(new FooModel()); with return MyView(new FooModel()) where MyView has more attributes than View class.

Comment: What are the extra attributes you want?  I'd guess your problem can be solved a different way.

Comment: What do you want achieve?

Comment: Try custom View Engine

Answer (score 2):

View() essentially instantiates an instance of [ViewResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewresult.aspx), so yes, you can define a method MyView() which instantiates a custom instance of ViewResult with more parameters.

Comment: I tried but didn't work and i want this class to be generic to use it in all controllers

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried and what you want to achieve?

Comment: this is my CustomView class: public class CustomView : ViewResult 
    {
        protected DbContainer DbContext = new DbContainer();
    } I use CustomView in this mode: public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return CustomView(new AddEditGrupareParametriiSistem());
        }

Comment: roroinpho21 What I meant to say is, it looks like you are passing your database to your view, in other words, you are are desecrating MVC the whole purpose of which is to separate concerns.